# Java apps consume 200% my CPU after cloning image in another computer

Tags: java, eclipse, openjdk, jdk, intellij

Yesterday I cloned an image of Linux from a Core 2 Duo to  a Core i5 laptop. Everything works as expected except for JVM. I've installed in my machine the OpenJDK, Java 8 (jdk jre) and Java 7 (jdk jre). All of them consume a lot of resources (CPU) when I run some IDE or some code. I notice this because the fan makes noise and even playing casual games this machine is pretty silent.

I checked the jvm flags, I added more resources for heap and some minor changes, I even I tried removing all flags, any change works...

I checked the swap partition and it's OK. The jvm config is the same in my second machine as it is in this machine. What can I do to fix it? I appreciate any help, thanks so much!!

Comment: Take a look at this question: [Eclipse uses 100 % CPU randomly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681989/eclipse-uses-100-cpu-randomly).